# Sending and receiving broadcast from the same receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-geofence

Hello I was trying to implement a custom Broadcast receiver for my Geofence app. I just went through the solution [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505614/android-geofence-eventually-stop-getting-transition-intents/19521823#19521823) But I found that he is sending the broadcast from the receiver class which receives the same broadcast. can someone please tell me how this works. I have not worked much on custom broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

He is sending the broadcast from one class and receiving it in another receiver. The line below is where he sends out the broadcast.

```
              Intent intent = new Intent("com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
```

Here is his manifest where he registers a receiver for that broadcast

```
   <receiver android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.GeofenceReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thank u for the answer. Can u tell me what this line means?
broadcastIntent
                    .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
                    .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_ID, geofenceIds)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_TYPE,
                            transitionType);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext())
                    .sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent); in the receiver class. This line confuses me

Answer (score 1):

you can send one Broadcast in another one with following code:

```
ntent local = new Intent();
local.setAction("BroadCastPath"); // like android.receiver.MyReceiver 
context.sendBroadcast(local);
```