# Android Geofence cannot call IntentService and cannot work inside BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, android-geofence

I have problem when I'm trying to use geofence with my app. I have succeed to register geofence but I have never get the notification.

First I follow the example that provide in http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html ,but the code never trigger intent service even I'm walking toward or away from area.

My code for register geofence and calling the intent service as follow :

inside manifest :

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.geofence.ReceiveTransitionsIntentService"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

in my MainActivity

```
    private boolean registerGeofence() {
        mRequestType = GeofenceUtils.REQUEST_TYPE.ADD;
        if (!servicesConnected()) {
            return false;
        }


        SimpleGeofence testGeo = new SimpleGeofence(Flag.GEOFENCE + "_"
                + 1, Double.valueOf("1.317342"),
                Double.valueOf("103.841998"), (float) (200),
                GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS,
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);

        mPrefs.setGeofence(Flag.GEOFENCE + "_" + 1, testGeo);
        mCurrentGeofences.add(testGeo.toGeofence());

        SimpleGeofence testGeo2 = new SimpleGeofence(Flag.GEOFENCE + "_"
                + 2, Double.valueOf("1.303961"),
                Double.valueOf("103.909356"), (float) (200),
                GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS,
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);

        mPrefs.setGeofence(Flag.GEOFENCE + "_" + 2, testGeo2);
        mCurrentGeofences.add(testGeo2.toGeofence());
        // end deleted this code after testing

        try {
            mGeofenceRequester.addGeofences(mCurrentGeofences);
            Log.e(TAG, "ADDING GEOFENCE ??? YES WE DID IT");
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    R.string.add_geofences_already_requested_error,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register the broadcast receiver to receive status updates
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```

in my GeofenceRequester

```
private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {
     Log.e(TAG, "CREATE REQUEST PENDING INTENT");
     // If the PendingIntent already exists
     if (null != mGeofencePendingIntent) {
     Log.e(TAG, "PENDING INTENT NOT NULL");
     return mGeofencePendingIntent;

     // If no PendingIntent exists
     } else {
     Log.e(TAG, "PENDING INTENT  NULL, LET'S CREATED IT");
     // Create an Intent pointing to the IntentService
     Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity,
     ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
     Log.e(TAG,
     return PendingIntent.getService(mActivity, 0, intent,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     }
```

and in class that subclass from IntentService remain same as an example.

I do search for this problem and found this solutions that describe on this link :
[Android Geofence eventually stop getting transition intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505614/android-geofence-eventually-stop-getting-transition-intents) ,so I change my code exactly as per suggestion, but still I cannot getting the notification, from my code inside GeofenceReceiver class, the code in this line

> LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

always return me -1 that means I never enter or leave the area (indicate GEOFENCE NEVER_EXPIRED),so I never get the notification. Please find below my GeofenceReceiver class :

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String TAG = GeofenceReceiver.class.getCanonicalName();
    Context context;
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
            handleError(intent);
        } else {
            handleEnterExit(intent);
        }
    }

    private void handleError(Intent intent) {
        int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);
        String errorMessage = LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(
                context, errorCode);
        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, context.getString(
                R.string.geofence_transition_error_detail, errorMessage));

        broadcastIntent.setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)
                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, errorMessage);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                broadcastIntent);
    }

    private void handleEnterExit(Intent intent) {

        int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

        // Test that a valid transition was reported
        if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {



            // Post a notification
            List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient
                    .getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
            String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
            String ids = TextUtils.join(GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER,
                    geofenceIds);
            String transitionType = getTransitionString(transition);

            for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size(); index++) {
                Geofence geofence = geofences.get(index);
                geofenceIds[index] = geofences.get(index).getRequestId();
            }

            sendNotification(transitionType, ids);

            // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
            broadcastIntent
                    .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
                    .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_ID, geofenceIds)
                    .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_TYPE,
                            transitionType);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                    broadcastIntent);

            // Log the transition type and a message
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, transitionType + ": " + ids);
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, context
                    .getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, "transition");
        } else {
            // Always log as an error
            Log.e(TAG, "TRANSITION = " + transition);
        }
    }
```

Kindly advise what should I do for fix this code and really appreciate for any kind help.

Comment: Can you please share your onReceiver code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for me I just changed some lines of code in **createPendingIntent** method

```
private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {
 Log.e(TAG, "CREATE REQUEST PENDING INTENT");
 // If the PendingIntent already exists
 if (null != mGeofencePendingIntent) {
 Log.e(TAG, "PENDING INTENT NOT NULL");
 return mGeofencePendingIntent;

 // If no PendingIntent exists
 } else {
 Log.e(TAG, "PENDING INTENT  NULL, LET'S CREATED IT");
 // Create an Intent pointing to the IntentService
 Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity,
 ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
 Log.e(TAG,
 return PendingIntent.getService(mActivity, 0, intent,
 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 }
```

So in place of **return PendingIntent.getService(mActivity, 0, intent,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);**

use this piece of cake 
**return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);**

and make sure you have declared your BroadcastReceiver in application manisfest file.Good luck!!!!

Comment: what should my broadcast receiver contain when i replace the line that you have mentioned

Answer (score 3):

**Beware:** Geofences are indeed being removed when Location Provider Settings change or the device is restarted. Unfortunately the Android documentation doesn't mention this anywhere.

To counter this, you can register for a Boot-Completed Receiver and a Location Provider Changed Receiver:

```
    <!-- Boot Completed Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name="com.mydemoapp.geofencing.BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Location Service Provider Changed Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name="com.mydemoapp.geofencing.LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Inside these two BroadcastReceivers you can implement your logic of re-registering your previously deleted geofences.

Comment: Note, you must hold the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in order to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` and it also seems you must hold either `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions to receive `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest you have registered the Service.

```
<service
android:name="com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.geofence.ReceiveTransitionsIntentService"
android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

But you have used broadcast receiver so can be an issue there. I am not sure about the broadcast receiver but with ReceiveTransitionIntent it does work as per the documentation.

However now i am stuck because when Location Service is Disabled or When Device is restarted i think Geofences are removed and I am not able to Add the Geofences back in Background.