# Not seeing Geofence Transitions in Google's tutorial on Geofencing

Tags: android, location, geofencing, android-geofence

I am trying to test Geofence functionality using [Google's example: Creating & Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). I have uploaded the [code here](https://bitbucket.org/mavme/google-geofence-example/src).

Problem is that I never get a notification of entry or exit. I have Wifi, 4G and GPS on. I have tried to test in the following ways:

1. I even walk out of my house for about 50ft and walk back in - but no notifications. I can see that play services gets connected and even the ["GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED in MainActivity.java"](https://bitbucket.org/mavme/google-geofence-example/src/447eea97b683acf96b0dd493237e65f42f2c36c8/src/com/example/android/geofence/MainActivity.java?at=master#cl-158) gets triggered, so I think Geofences are getting added correctly.
2. Enabled Mock Locations in the Settings and used this [Fake GPS App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps) and changed location - starting from the same coordinates as the Geofence1 and then setting to something totally outside (in another state) - but I still dont get an exit notification.

What am I doing wrong? ANyone had success in running this [Google's example: Creating & Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). I have uploaded the [code here](https://bitbucket.org/mavme/google-geofence-example/src) for easy browsing.

I am just trying to learn Geofencing - detecting entry & exit. **I WILL MARK ANY ANSWER AS THE RIGHT ANSWER THAT I CAN USE TO GET GEOFENCING WORKING ON MY REAL DEVICE**

[image: I enter the coordinates and radius below].

Comment: Actually there's a bug in android sample code.you should not use IntentService class for notification and transition.Replace it with BroadCastReceiver. Same issue is posted here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505614/android-geofence-eventually-stop-getting-transition-intents

Comment: Can you tell me how did you solve this issue ?

Comment: I did not, and that is why I have not marked the below answer as the right answer. I need to revisit this at some point .... sorry. If you find a way, would be awesome if you can post a solution please.

Comment: @user1406716 Did you get the problem solved ?

Comment: @Hunt No I did not have very good luck, I will probably come back  to this in future. If I do, will update here.

Answer (score 17):

I was also having issues with the example code. One of the main issues I had was around declaring the ReceiveTransitionsIntentService. You don't need to add a BroadcastReceiver or request location updates, but you need to change your AndroidManifest to set the exported value to true, like so:

```
<service
    android:name=".ReceiveTransitionsIntentService"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

Make sure that the path to the service is also correct.

I've simplified the Google example significantly and you can find the code and explanation [here](http://theandroidqueen.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/geofencing/). I've removed the UI component and persistent Geofence storage, so this example should be easier to follow. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey your blog is really helpful, thanks. I think there's an error in there, however - in the manifest section it lists `<service` .. `android:exported="false"`.  I think you mean `true`. Thanks!

Comment: @mari  I don't understand what different this could possibly have??  I mean, I've tried it and no dice.

Comment: This is a good answer... making android:exported="true" fixed the issue

Comment: I agree with other posted. This is the correct answer. Android Studio puts `android:exported="false"` when creating the IntentService. You have to go in the Manifest and change it to true. This answer should be marked as the solution.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much @mari

Answer (score 0):

Initally  my code was running smoothy but after that I too get this problem ,  Please try this by modifying geofenceRequester class in continueAddGeofences()  function.
basically it is calling the receiver through location request method

```
 private void continueAddGeofences() {


            // Get a PendingIntent that Location Services issues when a geofence
            // transition occurs
            mGeofencePendingIntent = createRequestPendingIntent();

            // Send a request to add the current geofences
            mLocationClient.addGeofences(mCurrentGeofences, mGeofencePendingIntent,
                    this);
            //mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            try {
                LocationRequest locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationrequest.setPriority(locationrequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                 locationrequest.setInterval(3000);


                mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, mGeofencePendingIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I got the notification once but not able to get it again. How are you testing you app? Are you using a mock locations app or actually walking away from the geofence coordinates? How far are you walking away?

Comment: I am actually walking away from the geofence coodinates and walking away depends upon radius that you have given , I have given 10m radius

Comment: is a radius like 5m or 10m working for you? and as you walk in and out - you see separate notifications showing entry and exit????

Comment: no, notifications replace the existing depends upon entering or exiting

Comment: @SpunkyPriya do i need to change something in BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: How are you testing this - on Genymotion or on a real device?  I am not getting any results...

Comment: on real device @IgorGanapolsky

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem with Geofence api. At the end, I used addProximityAlert of LocationManager.It did work very well!