# What is GeofenceUtils?

Tags: android, geofencing

i am building up android app project about geofence with reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505614/android-geofence-eventually-stop-getting-transition-intents/19521823#19521823**)
but I don't know GeofenceUtils in the link

```
broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);
```

What is GeofenceUtils?
I tried to find GeofenceUtils but I didn't find.
please would tell me about GeofenceUtils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the code you reference in your link, it looks like GeofenceUtils is a reference to a different part of his (b-ryce's) code. In other words he has written his own `static class` and defined all the constants he is using in within his app in that particular class.

What's confusing you is that he has called it GeofenceUtils, but rest assured it has nothing to do with the Google Play Geofencing stuff. He could just as easily have written

`broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.ATTR_CATEGORY);`

or

`broadcastIntent.addCategory("category");`